# Hypothetical malloc / free implementation with explicit size parameter to free

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Would there be any advantages to a dynamic memory allocation and deallocation API where the deallocation function requires the size?

More to the point, are there any interesting implementations of dynamic memory allocation that are off the table because `free` does not take the size as an argument?

The `malloc` and `free` library functions have an interesting asymmetry. `free` does not require the size of the `free`'d thing.

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

vs

```
void free(void *ptr);
```

Which means that a `malloc` implementation has to store the metadata somewhere so that `free` can do its job*.

If the API were instead:

```
void free(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

could you write an implementation of these functions that's more cache-efficient, uses less memory overall, or has more of some desirable property?

*I don't believe that requiring the size in order to free things would completely eliminate the need for storing metadata of some kind, but it could simplify it considerably.

Comment: Arghh... Manually freeing memory is hard enough without needing to track block sizes in application code. The number of use cases where you'd get any significant advantage with your scheme is small. It would be terribly error prone. However, it might be worthwhile for tiny embedded environments.  Note that there do exist allocation schemes requiring no per-allocation metadata.

Comment: Misuse of it may lead to memory leaks, say for example user allocates 20 bytes and frees only 4 bytes

Comment: @Gene Uh ... I'm not claiming that tracking block sizes is convenient or remotely competitive with not tracking them. I'm just wondering what you have to give up in order to not track them yourself. From your comment it sounds like the answer is "not much if anything".

Comment: An [awkwardly written, but good basic malloc introduction](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) that can answer some (if not all) of the reasons behind how the system handles the tracking of allocation size and why `free` need not provide a size is found in that tutorial (it was written for 32-bit allocations, but can be adapted for 64-bit use as well)

Comment: Yes at best you save 4 or 8 metadata bytes per allocation in the systems that store block size explicitly or use a block end pointer. For those that determine size by location, you save a lookup that's normally a few instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would there be any advantages to a dynamic memory allocation and deallocation API where the deallocation function requires the size?

Yes,  the user supplied size could be maybe compared against the system's understanding the the size. Alternativley the system would not need to even keep track of the size.

Yet there is a downside in the the user would then *need* to keep track.  The underlying allocation system  has more access to sizing info and can do so more efficiently and more faithfully than the user.

> ... uses less memory overall, ...

Not likely as the underlying allocation system can perform efficiency tricks beyond portable C better than the burden placed on the user to do the same.

---

The Standard C library design choice was made long ago favoring the underlying system keeping track.

---

A typical   wrapper can use `my_alloc(size)` and over-allocate to store meta data and `my_free(ptr, size)` to do this check.

Comment: The essay linked to by David Rankin mentions the key reasons why malloc almost certainly has to maintain metadata itself. When you free a block, the library not only needs to know the size of the block; it also needs to know whether the surrounding blocks are in use. If it cannot tell, it can't coalesce blocks, leading to much more fragmentation. The library could avoid this problem by dividing memory into fixed-size arenas, each of which contains blocks of a specific size. In that case, it can find the block's size from the arena metadata, so it doesn't need to be told.